# scatterplot: set hue to value of dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I made up this example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
y = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["1", "2", "3"])
```

[image: df.head()]

Now i want to scatterplot this example data.
I have tried around with seaborn:
Easiest way is this

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df)
```

which gives me nearly what i want:

[image: scatterplot1]

Now my question:
Is it possible to change y with the hue?
So that i have the my Colums as y-axis and the hue is based on the values of the cells.

[image: scatterplot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `melt` function with argument `ignore_index=False`:

```
y = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["1", "2", "3"])
df = pd.melt(df, var_name="y_val", value_name='hue', ignore_index=False)
sns.scatterplot(x=df.index, y="y_val", hue="hue", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]